# Checking files for any data corruption

Tags: linux, perl, encryption, corruption

How to check 2 same files for any data corruption while transferring it to from one OS(Linux) to another OS (Open VMS).

--- I am creating a single file on linux machine ,and transferring it by using sftp on to ovms machine.

Now, how do I check if the data in the files which I have sent is same or has been corrupted while transfer??

Comment: Compute a hash of the file and send it along with it, recompute the hash on the other side and compare them.

Comment: What Hunter McMillen said.  You can use the command line tool 'md5sum' or 'sha1sum' to compute those hashes.  See the respective man pages.  (Note that since sftp runs over SSH, you would probably have been told if there was a corruption during the transfer.  Corruption can still happen after the transfer though for any other reason.)

Comment: My Dear Friend As I have clearly mentioned I am using 2 different OS so even the hash what is generated over two OS are different so they cannot be comapred.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the thread in Super User [How to check if a file is corrupt or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15157/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-corrupt-or-not) , what about doing a `checksum`?

```
$ cksum faaa
4294967295 0 faaa
```

before sending it and after. Then compare the values. If equal, the sftp transfer was successful.

Comment: well I have clearly mentioned I am using two different os . So do you think the checksum generated will be same for the files over two different os ???
 And I don't think ovms supports this command checksum , only linux supports this.

Comment: From [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_file_verification), checkSum+ is OS compatible.